# Create controls based on properties of wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to start a project in C#, web or windows based so that I can test our WCF services. As we have alot of WCF projects, I had the idea to try to make it generic because else I would probably have to write over a hundred little tools. For my personal feel **Generic** is a must. The idea i had is to create controls based on the parameters.

Lets say I can enter the url in a form `localhost/Client/GetClientDetail.svc`.

The `GetClientDetail` method needs the following params:

```
string ClientName
enum Gender
bool IsActive
```

I would like if on my form/aspx page the controls can be generated dynamically:

```
string = textbox
enum = Dropdown
bool = Checkbox
```

Can you point me in the right direction or to an example online. I know of the windows tool that can do this, but I want to create something like that but on my own. The reason is that if I have a file I have to upload to a service, then I would notice the parameter is of type `byte` and I can then have my own usercontrol that I can have my form with a browse button to select the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the official `WCF Test Client`? If I recall correct it even shows automatically when you run a WCF service project in debug, and it pretty much exactly does what you need.

See this MSDN page: [WCF Test Client (WcfTestClient.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

*Edit because question changed to say the WcfTestClient is insufficient*

You could use a reflection tool (eg IlSpy) to see how the Microsoft test tool works, it is build in .NET itself. I started looking around and found the `Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.Workspace.AddServiceProject(...)` method. It does the following:

```
var serviceAnalyzer = new ServiceAnalyzer();
var serviceProject = serviceAnalyzer.AnalyzeService(
    endpoint, 
    addServiceWorker, 
    startProgress, 
    progressRange, 
    out error);
```

Where `endpoint` is a string containing the service endpoint Uri. Once inside the `ServiceAnalyzer` things get interesting and a bit out of scope for a simple SO answer. This would be a nice place to start looking for the way to build your own test tool.